# Android storage limit to use sdcard for each application

Tags: java, android, android-sdcard, android-permissions

I need to know is there any limit to use sdcard for each app? I'm trying to write video parts to scdard while camera app is recording and after 50mb (approximately not tested well) I got the error : "No space left". Although sdcard has 1.4 gb free space left. 
If there is a limit , how can I change or remove it?

Thanks

Edit: Full error message:

```
FileNotFoundException: /sdcard /20120905_180841_VIDEO_PART89.bin (No space left on device)
```

Here is my writing method:

```
private void write(byte[] DataByteArray, String DestinationFileName)
{

    OutputStream output = null;

    try {
        output = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(DestinationFileName)); //exception occurs here
        output.write( DataByteArray );        
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException ex){
        Log.e(Helper.LOG_TAG, "FileNotFoundException: " + ex.getMessage());
    }
    catch(IOException ex){
        Log.e(Helper.LOG_TAG, "IOException" +  ex.getMessage() + " " + ex.getClass());
    }
    finally {
        try {
            if(output != null)
                output.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(Helper.LOG_TAG, "IOException while closing output " + e.getMessage() + " " + e.getClass());
        } 
    }
```

Comment: As far as I know, there is no limit!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is there any limit to use sdcard for each app?

No.

> I'm trying to write video parts to scdard while camera app is recording and after 50mb (approximately not tested well) I got the error : "No space left".

Make sure that you are writing to external storage.

Comment: I edited my answer. I m using "BufferedOutputStream" to write to sdcard. And I'm sure that app is writing to external storage. Maybe there is a problem with BufferedOutputStream?

Comment: @buttib: You cannot have spaces in your path, as is shown in your LogCat error. Remove the space and try again. Also, your path is generally wrong -- please use `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` to get at the root of external storage (hint: it is not `/sdcard`), or better yet, use `getExternalFilesDir()` or `Environment.getExternalPublicStorageDirectory()` rather that dumping stuff in the root of external storage.

Comment: Actaully there no space in my path. I just passed it wrong. Anyway thank you for your help. Using 'Environment.getExternalPublicStorageDirectory()' solved my problem.